# Can any co-H space be represented as a suspension?

Tags: homotopy-theory

Given a co-H space $Y$, does there exist a space $X$ such that $Y\simeq \Sigma X$?
Dually, given a H space $Z$, does there exist a space $W$ such that $Z\simeq \Omega W$?
If not, any other relations are also okay.

Comment: For the dual question you need at least homotopy associativity which is not required for $H$-spaces. The precise condition for being a loop space is that $Z$ needs to be what is called a grouplike $E_1$-space, see https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/May+recognition+theorem.

Comment: Thank you for your remark.

Answer (score 4):

There are co-H spaces that are not suspensions; for example take an element of order 3 in $\pi_6(S^3)$and form a 2-cell complex. Then this is a co-H space that is not a suspension.  For more details, see the article on co-H structures by Arkowitz in the Handbook of Algebraic Topology.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

Comment: I could add that while this result is not elementary in my opinion, it does not rely on modern heavy duty machinery; rather on homotopy theory developed in the 50s and 60s., For your "dual" question, I expect there are H-Spaces that are not loop spaces and the book by Kane on H-Spaces might cover this. I don't have it handy to look into.